# HTML menu with sub-menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML menu with sub-menus and also sub-sub-menus. This code verifies each menu's trigger.  If clicked, sub-menu opens. Sub-menus also have triggers that open sub-sub-menus and so on. A working example can be found [here](http://bios-diagnostic.ro/meniu213/). This menu is a modified version of the menu found [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GoogleNexusWebsiteMenu/), made by Mary Lou. I want this to be my mobile menu but I don't want to manually enter all the cases.

My code is very lengthy and repetitive. How can I simplify it?

```
( function( window ) {
    'use strict';

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
        return check;
    }

    function gnMenu( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this._init();
    }

    function gnSubMenu( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this._init();
    }

    function gnSubMenu2( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this._init();
    }

    gnMenu.prototype = {
        _init : function() {
            this.trigger = this.el.querySelector( '.gn-icon-menu' );
            this.subtrigger = this.el.querySelector('.submenu' );
            this.subtrigger2 = this.el.querySelector('.submenu2' );
            this.menu = this.el.querySelector( '.menu-wrapper' );
            this.submenu = this.el.querySelector( '.sub-menu-wrapper1' );
            this.submenu2 = this.el.querySelector( '.sub-menu-wrapper2' );
            this.isMenuOpen = false;
            this.isSubMenuOpen = false;
            this.isSubMenu2Open = false;
            this.eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
            this._initEvents();
            var self = this;
            this.bodyClickFn = function() {
                self._closeMenu();
                self._closeSubMenu();
                self._closeSubMenu2();
                this.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
            };
        },
        _initEvents : function() {
            var self = this;
            if( !mobilecheck() ) {
                this.menu.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                    self._openMenu();
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                } );
                this.submenu.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                    self._openSubMenu();
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                } );
                this.submenu2.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                    self._openSubMenu2();
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                } );
            }
            this.trigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                if( self.isMenuOpen ) {
                    self._closeMenu();
                    document.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                }
                else {
                    self._openMenu();
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                }
            } );
            this.subtrigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                if( self.isSubMenuOpen ) {
                    self._closeSubMenu();
                    document.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                }
                else {
                    self._openSubMenu();
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                }
            } );
            this.subtrigger2.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                if( self.isSubMenu2Open ) {
                    self._closeSubMenu2();
                    document.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                }
                else {
                    self._openSubMenu2();
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
                }
            } );
            this.menu.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function(ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); } );
            this.submenu.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function(ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); } );
            this.submenu2.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function(ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); } );
        },
        _openMenu : function() {
            if( this.isMenuOpen )
                return;
            classie.add( this.trigger, 'gn-selected' );
            this.isMenuOpen = true;
            classie.add( this.menu, 'gn-open-all' );
        },
        _closeMenu : function() {
            if( !this.isMenuOpen )
                return;
            classie.remove( this.trigger, 'gn-selected' );
            this.isMenuOpen = false;
            classie.remove( this.menu, 'gn-open-all' );
        },
        _openSubMenu : function() {
            if( this.isSubMenuOpen )
                return;
            classie.add( this.subtrigger, 'gn-selected' );
            this.isSubMenuOpen = true;
            classie.add( this.submenu, 'gn-open-all2' );
        },
        _closeSubMenu : function() {
            if( !this.isSubMenuOpen )
                return;
            classie.remove( this.subtrigger, 'gn-selected' );
            this.isSubMenuOpen = false;
            classie.remove( this.submenu, 'gn-open-all2' );
        },
        _openSubMenu2 : function() {
            if( this.isSubMenu2Open )
                return;
            classie.add( this.subtrigger2, 'gn-selected' );
            this.isSubMenu2Open = true;
            classie.add( this.submenu2, 'gn-open-all3' );
        },
        _closeSubMenu2 : function() {
            if( !this.isSubMenu2Open )
                return;
            classie.remove( this.subtrigger2, 'gn-selected' );
            this.isSubMenu2Open = false;
            classie.remove( this.submenu2, 'gn-open-all3' );
        }
    };
    // Add to global namespace
    window.gnMenu = gnMenu;
} )( window );
```

Comment: Well, you could **start with proper intendation**! After that, factor out common stuff. Functions are not special, so you could do `var gnSubMenu = gnMenu, gnSubMenu2 = gnMenu;` instead of defining three identical functions. Use loops for repetitive code (e.g. over the `addEventListener`). After that you can start with actual refactoring (e.g. choosing better names).

Comment: @amon y u answer in comments?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I saw right away, while I was editing your question to make it more noticeable, is that you have 3 functions that are the same, they just have different names.

> ```
> function gnMenu( el, options ) {
>     this.el = el;
>     this._init();
> }
>
> function gnSubMenu( el, options ) {
>     this.el = el;
>     this._init();
> }
>
> function gnSubMenu2( el, options ) {
>     this.el = el;
>     this._init();
> }
> ```

You don't need to do this.  It looks like they all take in the same parameters and do the same thing, so just use one function for the 3 of them.

```
function menu( el, options ) {
    this.el = el;
    this._init();
}
```

One step to being DRYer already (*DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself*)